# What happened to Moshe's altar?

Tags: mizbeach-altar

After the battle with Amalek, Moshe builds an altar (Mizbeach) called "Hashem Nisi" (God is my miracle). Was anything offered on it, who performed the service, and does it have any kedusha or significance.

Comment: Building alters (without mention of what was done with them) was quite common ([Bereshit 12:7-8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.12.7-8?lang=bi&lang2=en), [ibid. 13:18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.13.18?lang=bi&lang2=en), [ibid. 26:25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.26.25?lang=bi&lang2=en), [ibid. 35:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.35.7?lang=bi&lang2=en), [Shofetim 6:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.6.24?&lang=bi&lang2=en), [I Shemuel 7:17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.7.17?&lang=bi&lang2=en)).